# What is Lucene equivalent for QueryBuilders.nestedQuery in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, lucene

In `Elasticsearch 7.12` I can build a nested query this way:

```
QueryBuilder nestedQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(nestedPath, query, ScoreMode.Min)
                                .ignoreUnmapped(true);
```

- How can I do the same in `Lucene 9` ?
- I expect to build an instance of Lucene Query object or Builder of some kind of Lucene Query class.

Comment: Could you clarify your question. Nested documents is an Elasticsearch concept. It includes both specially indexed documents as well as a special query that is defined in Elasticsearch project and doesn't exist in Lucene. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to use Lucene to search an elasticsearch index or do you want to achive a similar functionality completely in Lucene?

Comment: QueryBuilders has nothing to do with Lucene, it's an [Elasticsearch Java class](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryBuilders.java#L490-L492) which is stil present in the latest ES release.